# Restrict SliderInput in R Shiny date range to weekdays

Tags: r, shiny

I have a DF with a field for weekday dates between 2021-01-01 and yesterday. I have a SliderInput that has the min and max values set for the same range. In the SliderInput, it is still possible to see weekend dates and pick a date that does not exist in the DF, which is weekdays only. If someone does this, they see an error instead of the plots. Any way to specify only weekdays in the SliderInput or point it just to the values in the DF?

SliderInput:

```
sliderInput(inputId = "trajectory", 
                    label = "Date Range:",
                    min = as.Date(min(DF$dates),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                    max = as.Date(max(DF$dates),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                    value = c(as.Date(today() - 180), as.Date(Sys.Date()-1)))
```

Comment: Would you consider using `dateInput` instead of `sliderInput`? You then can use `daysofweekdisabled = c(0,6)` to remove weekend dates.

Comment: Thanks! Form follows function. But, would still need dateRangeInput or two dateInputs. Nice workaround. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and this worked for me. The solution relies on `shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput()`. For this to work you must define your choices of dates and default values up front (I'd recommend somewhere before the UI):

```
#packages
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)

#date choices
choices <- seq.Date(date("2021-01-01", today() - 1, by = 1) 
choices <- choices[!wday(choices) %in% c(1, 7)] #removes weekends
default <- seq.Date(today() - 182, today() - 180, by = 1) 
default <- default[!wday(default) %in% c(1, 7)]
default <- max(default) #most recent weekday
```

Then you want to stick this within the appropriate place in your UI in place of `sliderInput()`:

```
sliderTextInput("trajectory", "Date Range:", choices = choices,
                selected = c(default, max(choices)))
```

You'll retain many of the benefits of `sliderInput` doing it this way, but you may have to work with the `grid` option to get tick marks and labels to your liking.